# Javascript html copy button

Tags: javascript

In my function command() there is a varaible called result4

I also have a function copy_to_clipboard(id) which copies the text in texture with Id result. However I want this function to copy the var result4 from the command() function. How do I do this:

```
<button class="button" onclick="command();copy_to_clipboard('html');">Submit</button><br><br>
<script>
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = command;

  function command() {
    if (document.getElementById('essentials').checked) {
      initiation = "minecraft:";
    } else {
      initiation = "";
    }
    if (document.getElementById('glow').checked) {
      glow = "glowstone";
    } else {
      glow = "glass";
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("form");
    var block = x.elements["block"].value;;
    var type = x.elements["type"].value;

    var replace_block = '"stone';
    var replace_type = 'Damage:0s';
    var replace_initiation = "minecraft:";
    var replace_glowstone = "glowstone";
    var filter1 = new RegExp(replace_block, 'g');
    var filter2 = new RegExp(replace_type, 'g');
    var filter3 = new RegExp(replace_glowstone, 'g');
    var filter4 = new RegExp(replace_initiation, 'g');
    var command =

      `/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ { 

Block:command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/fill ~1 ~-1 ~1 ~-1 ~53 ~-1 air" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:0,Command:"/fill ~1 ~ ~1 ~-1 ~53 ~-1 air" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:repeating_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.063 ~-1.9981 ~0.063 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.063 ~-1.9982 ~-0.063 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.063 ~-1.9983 ~-0.063 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.063 ~-1.9984 ~0.063 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~ ~-1.998 ~ /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.3 ~-0.579 ~-0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[135f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.113 ~-0.579 ~-0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[135f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.074 ~-0.579 ~-0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[135f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.261 ~-0.579 ~-0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[135f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.261 ~-0.579 ~0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[315f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.074 ~-0.579 ~0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[315f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.113 ~-0.579 ~0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[315f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.3 ~-0.579 ~0.06 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[315f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.059 ~-0.579 ~-0.302 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[45f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.059 ~-0.579 ~-0.115 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[45f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.059 ~-0.579 ~0.072 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[45f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.059 ~-0.579 ~0.259 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[45f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.060 ~-0.579 ~-0.260 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[225f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.060 ~-0.579 ~-0.073 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[225f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.060 ~-0.579 ~0.114 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[225f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.060 ~-0.579 ~0.301 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Small:1b,Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[225f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583,Pose:{RightArm:[345f,0f,0f]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.2203 ~-1.495 ~0.156 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.2206 ~-1.495 ~-0.156 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.2209 ~-1.432 ~0.155 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.2212 ~-1.432 ~-0.156 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.156 ~-1.495 ~0.2203 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[90f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.155 ~-1.495 ~0.2206 

/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[90f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.156 ~-1.432 ~0.2209 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[90f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.155 ~-1.432 ~0.2212 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[90f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.2203 ~-1.495 ~-0.156 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[180f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.2206 ~-1.495 ~0.155 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[180f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.2209 ~-1.432 ~-0.156 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[180f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.2212 ~-1.432 ~0.155 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[180f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.156 ~-1.495 ~-0.2206 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[270f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.155 ~-1.495 ~-0.2203 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[270f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.156 ~-1.432 ~-0.2212 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[270f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.155 ~-1.432 ~-0.2209 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, Rotation:[270f],Small:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~ ~-1 ~ /setblock ~ ~ ~ glowstone 0" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.1881 ~-2.8751 ~0.1881 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.1883 ~-2.8753 ~-0.1883 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~-0.1885 ~-2.8755 ~0.1885 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~0.1887 ~-2.8757 ~-0.1887 /summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b, ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:\\"stone\\",Damage:0s,Count:1b}],HandItems:[{},{}],CustomName:\\"Chest\\",DisabledSlots:2039583}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/minecraft:tp @e[type=Creeper,name=Chest] ~ -100 ~" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:repeating_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/execute @e[type=Creeper,name=Remove] ~ ~ ~ /minecraft:kill @e[type=armor_stand,r=3,name=Chest]" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:chain_command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/minecraft:tp @e[type=Creeper,name=Remove] ~ -100 ~" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 51 {HideFlags:33,display:{Name:\\"Create Chest\\"},ench:[{id:1,lvl:0}],EntityTag:{id:\\"Creeper\\",CustomName:\\"Chest\\", ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:100,ShowParticles:0b}]}}" } ,Passengers:[{ id:falling_block,Block:command_block,Data:1,Time:1,TileEntityData:{ auto:1,Command:"/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 51 {HideFlags:33,display:{Name:\\"Remove Chest\\"},ench:[{id:1,lvl:0}],EntityTag:{id:\\"Creeper\\",CustomName:\\"Remove\\", ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:100,ShowParticles:0b}]}}" } }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] } `;
    var result1 = command.replace(filter1, '"' + block);
    var result2 = result1.replace(filter2, 'Damage:' + type + 's');
    var result3 = result2.replace(filter3, glow);
    var result4 = result3.replace(filter4, initiation);
    document.getElementById("result").value = result4;
  }

  function copy_to_clipboard(id) {
    document.getElementById('result').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
  }
</script>
<textarea id="result" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea><br>
```

Comment: does not workfunction copy_to_clipboard(result4){
          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to copy `result4` you have to do three things:

1. Create a temporary `textarea` and put it in the `body`.
2. Set `result4` as its value and select it.
3. Use `execCommand` to copy it and then delete the `textarea`.

**Code:**

*<sup>(put this code after yours inside the 'command' function)</sup>*

```
/* Create a temporary 'textarea' element. */
var temp = document.createElement("textarea");

/* Put the textarea to the body. */
document.body.appendChild(temp);

/* Set 'result4' as its value. */
temp.value = result4;

/* Select the textarea's content. */
temp.select();

/* Copy the selected text to the clipboard. */
document.execCommand("copy");

/* Delete the textarea. */
document.body.removeChild(temp);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function command () {
  /* Your previous code... */
  var result4 = "result4";
  
  /* ---------- Solution ---------- */

  /* Create a temporary 'textarea' element. */
  var temp = document.createElement("textarea");

  /* Put the textarea to the body. */
  document.body.appendChild(temp);

  /* Set 'result4' as its value. */
  temp.value = result4;

  /* Select the textarea's content. */
  temp.select();

  /* Copy the selected text to the clipboard. */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  /* Delete the textarea. */
  document.body.removeChild(temp);
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<button class="button" onclick="command()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, here if the final result http://100awesomecraft.com/commands/creations/colored-chest.html

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @100Awesome 